# How to replace backslashes with forward slashes in all #include "...\..."

Tags: regex, perl, sed

I am wondering if it is possible to replace in files statements like:

```
#include "foo\bar\something\else"
#include "..\..\foo.h"
```

with

```
#include "foo/bar/something/else"
#include "../../foo.h"
```

I can use Perl pie or sed multiple times with:

```
s|(\#include.*)\\|\1/|
```

But I would like to know if there is something like a first directive in a regex *i.e.* `s|^#include\Z\\|/|g` where `\Z` is the modifier I am looking for.

**EDIT**
Of course I shall only replace backslashes on a #include directive.

```
s@\@/@g
```

Will not work in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's~(?:#include|(?!^)\G)[^\\]*\K\\~/~g' file
#include "foo/bar/something/else"
#include "../../foo.h"
```

Using `sed`:

```
sed '/#include/s~\\~/~g' file
#include "foo/bar/something/else"
#include "../../foo.h"
```

Or if you want to replace all `\` with `/` then use `tr`:

```
tr '\\' "/" < file
#include "foo/bar/something/else"
#include "../../foo.h"
```

Comment: What if there are other backslashes in the file that OP wants to keep?

Comment: Yes I updated the answer with more precise regex using `perl`

Comment: Excellent, this is exactly what I was looking for. However, does somebody knows why it works with Perl, but not with PCRE? https://regex101.com/r/cL3iU3/1

Comment: Actually it works, just need to exclude `\n` in regex match. [See this demo](https://regex101.com/r/vE8mX2/1)

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -pe'tr{\\}{/} if /^\s*#\s*include/'
```

Some of the text is matched against twice, but the amount is very minor. The alternative (as seen in anubhava's answer) is rather messy and probably ends up being no faster than matching against some of the text twice.

A `sed` version of this approach has since been added to anubhava's answer, and it's faster.

Comment: Actually in my brief testing `sed` solution is coming up way faster than both `perl` solutions

Comment: I'm surprised at all. I hadn't noticed your `sed` solution, and I have adjusted my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can use `sed`

```
sed 's|\|/||g' file
#include "foo\bar\something\else"
#include "..\..\foo.h"
```

Replace only in lines with `#include`

```
sed '/#include/s|\\|/|g' file
#include "foo/bar/something/else"
#include "../../foo.h"
```

```
awk '/^#include/ {gsub(/\\/,"/")}1' file
#include "foo/bar/something/else"
#include "../../foo.h"
```