# Understanding \G and \K in regex

Tags: regex

In a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28837660/how-to-replace-backslashes-with-forward-slashes-in-all-include), I asked to match chars that follow a specific pattern. In order to be more specific, I would like to consider this example:

We want to match all the `x` that follow `b` or `d`. We may want to replace these characters with `o`:

```
-a  x   x    xx x  x
-b x  x x   x   xx x
-c  x  x   x   x x x
-d x  x   x  xx x  x
```

The result would be this:

```
-a  x   x    xx x  x
-b o  o o   o   oo o
-c  x  x   x   x x x
-d o  o   o  oo o  o
```

[anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava) answered my question with a pretty nice regex that has the same form as this one:

```
/([db]|\G)[^x-]*\Kx/g
```

Unfortunately I did not completely understand how `\G` and `\K` work. I would like to have a more detailed explaination on this specific case.

I tried to use the Perl regex debugger, but It is a bit cryptic.

```
Compiling REx "([db]|\G)[^x-]*\Kx"
Final program:
   1: OPEN1 (3)
   3:   BRANCH (15)
   4:     ANYOF[bd][] (17)
  15:   BRANCH (FAIL)
  16:     GPOS (17)
  17: CLOSE1 (19)
  19: STAR (31)
  20:   ANYOF[\x00-,.-wy-\xff][{unicode_all}] (0)
  31: KEEPS (32)
  32: EXACT <x> (34)
  34: END (0)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Correct regex is:

```
(-[db]|(?!^)\G)[^x-]*\Kx
```

[Check this demo](https://regex101.com/r/nI3zB6/2)

As per the regex101 description:

`\G` - asserts position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match. `\G` will match start of line as well for the very first match hence there is a need of negative lookahead here `(?!^)`

`\K` - resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match. `\K` will discard all matched input hence we can avoid back-reference in replacement.

- [More details about \K](http://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html)
- [More details about \G](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html)

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest not doing it in one regex.  Your intent is much more clear if you do this:

```
if ( /^-[bd]/ ) {  # If it's a line that starts with -b or -d...
    s/x/o/g;       # ... replace the x's with o's.
}
```

If that's too many lines for you, you could even do:

```
s/x/o/g if /^-[bd]/;
```

Comment: Yes it is a good way to do it but my question was more about a oneliner with a single regex to understand `\G` and `\K`

Comment: Upvoted this because I sometimes multiple regexes sometimes prove both easier to create and better performing than a more difficult to understand single line. This isn't the answer but it does contribute to the conversation.